# Animated series with a family of monsters that eat garbage

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

If anyone can help me about a animated series with a family of monsters with different colors that eat garbage and it's a little boy too.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? Was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated? And when you said _"and it's a little boy too"_, did you mean that there's a little boy monster too? Or that there's a little human boy?

Comment: It is not the Ogglies ?  It is a family of monsters that hangs out with kids,  and they eat garbage. They are all green though.

Comment: do they live in boxes?